# Changing the IPython interpreter

Tags: python, ipython, kdb, q-lang, pyq

I'm using Python with kdb+. To do this I'm using [PyQ](http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/pyq/), which brings Python and kdb+/Q to the same process and allows both languages to operate on the same set of data/memory space.

After some effort, I am able to load Python into the kdb+/Q process on OS X using the instructions from [here](http://code.kx.com/wsvn/code/contrib/serpent.speak/trunk/Q/README), i.e. running

```
q python.q [-<python option>@ <python option value>]* python-script
```

This is all good, but I would like to use the above command as interpreter in IPython (Notebook for research, etc.).

So, how do you change the interpreter in IPython? I've seen the FAQ [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions), but creating a virtual environment doesn't seem like the solution. Ideally I would create a profile for IPython.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the latest version of PyQ using the following pip command:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.enlnt.com --no-binary pyq pyq
```

This should install a `pyq` executable.  To run `IPython`, do

```
pyq -mIPython
```

For more information about PyQ and IPython, see my presentation ["Exploring KDB+ Data in IPython Notebooks"](https://pyq.enlnt.com/slides).