# Ipython notebook: ImportError: No module named graphlab

Tags: python, ipython

These days I'm trying to import '**graphlab**' for **ipython notebook**, but it shows '**ImportError**', but it works when I directly type the '**import graphlab**' in the terminal.

I cannot figure out why,  very appreciated if someone could help me to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: You need to tell ipython to use the same pyhton interpreter that has the graphlap package installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the IPython interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560086/changing-the-ipython-interpreter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I follow the tips to append the lib path to the sys.path:['', ... ... 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages'], but the notebook still cannot recognize the module, it is strange.  is there somewhere I missed? thank you